# Connecting mySql Databases for Windows Service

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services

So I have a basic running windows service which needs to copy all data from one MySQL Connection to another broken down as:

MySQL Connection A has 5 Schemas and each schema has several tables.

I need to copy all 5 Schemas and all the tables within those schemas from MySQL Connection A to MySQL Connection B.

When run the first time It needs to automatically recreate the schemas and layouts to place the data into MYSQL Connection B. Once that has done it has to run once a day at 3am till 5am constantly overwriting Connection B Where there have been changes in Connection A.

I have got the basics the service runs and works however its not actually accessing the databases at all!

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class BackupService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer1 = null;
    bool backUpRunning = false;

    public BackupService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        timer1 = new Timer();
        this.timer1.Interval = 3600000;
        this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Backup window service started");

    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);


        LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Checking if it's time to run the backup service and checking if the service is already running");

        if (backUpRunning)
            LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Service is already running");

        if ((now > start) && (now < end) && !backUpRunning)
        {
            LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Service is not already running and the time of day is valid to run the service.");
            try
            {
                backUpRunning = true;
                LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Initialising backup service");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("The backup service failed. It will return to step 1 and try again: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                backUpRunning = false;
            }
        }
        LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Timer ticked and job has been done successfully");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        timer1.Stop();
        LogLibrary.WriteErrorLog("Service stopped");
    }
 private void Backup()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        string constring = "server=; user=root; pwd=; database=testing;";
        string file = "C:\\backup.sql";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM testing"))
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();

                    //mb.ExportInfo.AddCreateDatabase = true;
                    //mb.ExportInfo.ExportTableStructure = true;
                    //mb.ExportInfo.ExportRows = true;
                    mb.ExportToFile(file);

                    conn.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    //IMPORT DATABASES to Gunther
    private void Restore()
    {
        string constring = "server=; user=root; pwd=; database=testingbackup;";
        string file = "C:\\backup.sql";


        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT  ALL INTO testingbackup"))
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();

                    //mb.ImportInfo.TargetDatabase = "testingbackup";
                    //mb.ImportInfo.DatabaseDefaultCharSet = "utf8";
                    mb.ImportFromFile(file);

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

SERVER DETAILS AND PASSWORDS HAVE BEEN REMOVED FOR BUSINESS REASONS but the server i would normally input the connection address which is eg. 00.250.250.250:3306 and 11.250.250.250:3306

Comment: You need to call the methods (`backup` or `restore`) from the `timer's elapsed` event.

Comment: @Taleeb, I have done this and reduced my ticker to check the time at 5 minute intervals and all that my logger has logged is that the backup window service started but hasn't logged any other information and has not actually made any changes to the databases

Comment: 3600000 is 60 minutes (not 5). So timer_tick should execute after an hour. Also there is no code calling the `Backup` or `Restore` method - which, I believe, would make changes to db

Comment: I changed the timer from 3600000 to 300000 and called backup() and Restore() in the time elapsed method as you suggested although its not working. its seeming to run but not completing any action so I am starting to think i have a connection issue

Comment: Good to know that the control is reaching the code. You can debug by adding `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` or `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in your code.